# TS errors while importing modules in files of shared directory

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have a problem with using npm `@types` typings in shared directory to packages like `react`, `lodash`, etc. The problem disappears when I install typings via `typings`, but I really like types versioning that npm introduced and those seem to be up to date.

Let's say this is some repository structure:

```
projects/
    app1/
        App.tsx
        webpack.config.js
        (...)
    app2/
        App.tsx
        (...)
    shared/
        Test.tsx
```

When `shared/test.tsx` imports React like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
```

and `app1/app.tsx` imports `Test` component like:

```
import {Test} from "../shared/test";
```

I see TS errors:

```
ERROR in ../shared/Test.tsx
(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react'.

ERROR in ./App.tsx
(25,17): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Test' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
Property 'setState' is missing in type 'Test'.
```

This happens only to imports from files that are located outside of directory where webpack-config resides.
Moreover after compilation `Test` component is successfully displayed in `App` component so webpack combined those two, but TS errors still shine in console.

I use Webpack 2.2.0 with `ts-loader` (but tried `awesome-typescript-loader`) as well and tried to add some config paths to webpack's `resolve.modules` and tsconfig's `compilerOptions.rootPaths` but achieved nothing.

I feel like there may be some way in `webpack` or `ts-loader` config or maybe I could write some typings that would re-export those from `node_modules/@types/`.
How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to put this line `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` into your `tsconfig.json`. It helped me.